# Resolving memory leak in wicket

Tags: memory-leaks, wicket

We have a wicket application which goes out of memory. I get following error.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

When I took heap dump, I can see following

[image]

My code looks like below.

```
public class CommonPanel extends Panel {

    private static ResourceModel SUCCESS_MESSAGE;
    private static ResourceModel VALIDATE_ZERO_MSG;
    private static Model<SomeInfoObject> someInfo;

    public CommonPanel(String id, boolean isRedirect) {
        super(id);

        someInfo = Model.of();

        SUCCESS_MESSAGE = new ResourceModel("successMessage");
        VALIDATE_ZERO_MSG = new ResourceModel("zero.message");

        Form<MyObject> form = new Form<>("myForm", new CompoundPropertyModel<>(new MyObject()));
        Label successLabel= new Label("success", SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
        add(successLabel.setVisible(isRedirect));
        add(new Label("title", getPanelTitle(id)));

        FeedbackPanel errorFeedbackPanel = new BootstrapFilteredFeedbackPanel("errorFeedbackPanel", FeedbackType.ERROR);
        errorFeedbackPanel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        form.add(errorFeedbackPanel);

        SomeInfoPanel someInfoPanel = new SomeInfoPanel("somePanel", someInfo);
        someInfoPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        someInfoPanel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        form.add(someInfoPanel);

//...................more code here

     }

     @Override
     public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        SUCCESS_MESSAGE.detach();
        VALIDATE_ZERO_MSG.detach();
        someInfo.detach();
     }
}

public class SomeInfoPanel extends Panel {

    public SomeInfoPanel(String id, IModel<SomeObject> model) {
        super(id, model);
        add(new FallbackLabel("name", PropertyModel.of(model, "someName"), ""));
    }    
}
```

From what I read, wicket serialize instance of this class and stores in session. Is it the cause of this leak ? how to prevent this ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Wicket pages are not GC-ed and they keep all their components around.

I'd suggest you to take a heap dump and see how these references are kept in the classloader. Eclipse Memory Analyzer (http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) is very good tool for this.

Another good tool is Intellij IDEA Memory View (https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/08/jvm-debugger-memory-view-for-intellij-idea/).

Comment: As you can see above, I used jMat to analyse heap dump. "how these references are kept in the classloader..." Can you elaborate a little ?you mean who is referring to this object ?

Comment: Right. You need to find the path from the object to the class loader. This way you will be able to understand why they are not GC-ed.